# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.GetConf on Hadoop

Tags: java, apache, hadoop

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.GetConf
```

Starting namenodes on []
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ingreens-namenode-ingreens-desktop.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ingreens-datanode-ingreens-desktop.out
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.GetConf

and jps show

13033 Jps
12873 DataNode

using Hadoop 2.6.0

what shoul i do.

Comment: could you post your configuration files?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem! I solve that changing .bashrc file. Add these lines to the end of the $HOME/.bashrc file, changing the hadoop installation path:

```
<code>
#Set hadoop-related enviroment variables
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export YARN_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_CONFDIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop
# Native path
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=${HADOOP_PREFIX}/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=${HADOOP_PREFIX}/lib/native"
export JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native:$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH
# Add Hadoop bin/ directory to PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
</code>
```

I hope this help someone